# Angular route: redirectTo when using multiple param

Tags: angular, angular-router

I have a route like this

```
const pipelinesRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: ':type',
    component: CatalogComponent,
    canActivate: [LoggedInGuard],
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: CatalogContentComponent,
      },
      {
        path: ':domain/:categoryId',
        component: CatalogContentComponent,
      },
    ],
  },
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'skills', canActivate: [LoggedInGuard] },
];
```

Here i want to redirect my app to skills(:type) if no type is provided , it works fine on start, but once i refresh say having this url.

```
catalog/skills/technical
```

it redirect to

```
catalog/skills/skills/technical
```

Comment: Not working tried pathMatch prefix/full

Comment: Please explain what is the purpose of `:domain` and `:categoryId`

Comment: In `catalog/skills/technical` if `skills` is the `:type` then there is no path match for `technical` as it only accepts `:domain/:categoyId`

Comment: @T.SunilRao Yes that was the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks T. Sunil Rao for helping me.
Yes my route was having issue.
I was passing empty param while routing with help of

```
this.router.navigate([domain, ''], { relativeTo: this.route });
```

But while refresh it doesn't treat that empty param as param so rediercting.

catalog/skills/technical doesn't full fill any route so it redirect to skills/
Correct route should be

```
const pipelinesRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'skills', pathMatch: 'full' },
  {
    path: ':type',
    component: CatalogComponent,
    canActivate: [LoggedInGuard],
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: NoDomainContentComponent,
      },
      {
        path: ':domain',
        component: CatalogContentComponent,
        children: [
          {
            path: ':categoryId',
            component: CatalogContentComponent,
          },
        ]
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

Using child of another since i don't want to refresh the component, want to use same  component and just filter the data.